# how to access this nested objects value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, frontend

I want to access this "code:ENABLE_CO" in angular
I have tried, the following code nothing has been worked for me. for your reference i have attached the image, anyone please help me out for this

it is the dynamic one . and i need both the key and value and the structure may differ.

```
 if(user.authorizations)
        {
           
            user.authorizations.forEach(obj=>
                {
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
                    {
                        console.log(key);
                        console.log(value);
                        if(value=="ENABLE_COMPANY_CODE")
                        {
                            console.log("value is"+value);
                        }
                    }

                })
            
        }
```

=

[image]

Comment: How does your `user.authorizations` look like?

Comment: Please provide the context. Is it a dynamic, changable content, or static? Does it always have the same structure/keyes, but possibly different values? Do you only need the key that has that value, or only the value of that particular key?

Comment: @AdityaParab this is my user.authorizations, if i console.log(user.authorizations)  i got this

Comment: @MishaMashina it is the dynamic one, i need both key and value. . sturcture will different for different scenerios

Comment: Then, if you cannot expect that the structure will be the same for each possible object in `user.authorizations` array (i.e. that it will have `screens` and `functionalities`) and you can also have `code` key in upper-level objects (i.e. not the ones you're looking for), it might be a good idea to use for loops to iterate over objects, then if clause to test it if has `screens`, then for-loop again to iterate over screens objects and check if they have `functionalities`, then iterate again through functionalities objects and find the value of the `code`.

Comment: Of course, things might be a lot different if some parts of the structure are always expected to be present. I say for-loops to easily break out if you need, but it again depends on what you want to do once you grab the key/value.